# How to dynamically output current time per timezone in php?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a timezone stored in each node and want to display current time per node, depending on the timezone set.

E. g. there is a node America/Sao_Paulo - a stored timezone would be 'America/Sao_Paulo'.

In order to display timezone in tz format, I have to print it with this code (Drupal 7):

```
<?php print $node->field_mytimezone['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

The result would be:

```
America/Sao_Paulo
```

How to dinamically change that part in php code? I have tried with this:

```
<?php $zone='<?php print $node->field_mytimezone['und'][0]['value']; ?>'; ?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('$zone');
echo date('H:i');
?>
```

Nesting obviously doesn't work, but I don't know how to properly implement it while preserving the first part (the one that outputs timezone in tz format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you're after but if the timezone string is stored in `$node->field_mytimezone['und'][0]['value']` the following code should give you an idea of how to use it:

```
$zone = $node->field_mytimezone['und'][0]['value'];

$dt = new DateTime();

$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($zone));

echo $dt->format('H:i');
```

Comment: You're right, it's a bit confusing. The end result should be something like 09:10. That time would be different for each node, depending on the timezone set.